# Javascript. Var++ not properly working

Tags: javascript, recursion

I've been learning JS for a few days. stackoverflow was a great help. However I came up with a problem I cannot even determine or describe (since I'm new to this).

I've built an < audio >-based mp3 player.
You need to see /try it by yourself. (sorry)

[Please check JS code here - ctrl-f 'STACKoverflow' in it - AntonFrolov.net/music.php](http://AntonFrolov.net/music.php)

Here is the actions you need to perform to see where the problem is (I've put these to website too).

1. Click on track #2 - You will notice an alert('Track #' +ID); = [Track #2]
2. There is a player in the bottom-right corner - Set track progress to 98% so it ends.
3. (ID++), You are sent to the track#3 . alert('Track #' +ID); = [Track #3]. good.
4. Repeat step 2.
5. (ID++), You should be sent to the track#4. ... PROBLEM Events:

   - 5a. alert('Track #' +ID); = [Track #3].
   - 5b. Track#3 starts playing. AGAIN. then you instantly receive next .. alert
   - 5c. alert('Track #' +ID); = [Track #4].
   - 5d. Track#4 starts playing. that's what I expected but without events 5a-5b.

This will continue if you keep doing the steps.

However the JS code is here:

```
    function FuncPlay(ID,Rnd){
    alert('Track #'+ID);
    if (Rnd==0){
    $('.liActive').removeClass('liActive');
    $('#'+ID).next().addClass('liActive');


    // Set track Data
    $('audio').attr('id','audioNor');
    $('audio').attr('src',$('.liActive').attr('rel'));

    // Play
    var player = $('.tbd').get(0);
    player.play();
    $('#pause').removeClass('hi');
    ID++;
        $(player).bind('ended', function () { 
                if (ID <= <?php echo $am ?>){FuncPlay(ID, 0);}
                else {alert('"...End of the list."' );}
        });
    }
}
```

I have completely no idea how to deal with this. Thank you for your patience.

Comment: DId you try console.log and debug?

Comment: Tried but not successfully. Since I'm not used to debugging. Are Firebug tools the ones I need? Console returns no errors. Looking for a way to trace the bug via Script panel

Comment: Is this JS being outputted by PHP?

Comment: absolutely not. it's in the end of the page if you ctrlf 'JSoverflow'

Comment: Perhaps ID is a string and you have to convert it to Number?

Comment: when I do ID++ it adds +1. Would that be possible for a string value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is that you're binding the `ended`-handler multiple times to your player. Everytime FuncPlay gets called, it will be attached another time.
So for example if then track 5 starts, it will first call the handler for track 3, then track 4 and finally track 5.

What you could do is creating a global variable called `ID` and bind to the handler only when  `document ready` is called. In the handler-function you refer to this global variable.
Or, before calling `$(player).bind`, remove all bindings to the players `ended` event.

Also, I would recommend using `.on()`, `.bind()` is just still available for backwards compatibility. The method to unbind the event-handler is `.off()`/`.unbind()`.

Comment: $(player).unbind('ended'); seems to be working, is that the correct way?

Comment: It's one correct way, but better use `.on`/`.off` instead of `.bind`/`.unbind` (just replace "bind" with "on" and "unbind" with "off")

Comment: Thanks you very much, sir. I'm still willing to pass a beer, so send me a PM with paypal please. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You don't unbind you 'ended' event listener. Is is called 2 times on the second song end, 3 times on the third, etc.